# Undefined when referencing an object via another object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My question is pretty simple. I'm creating two objects. The second object is referencing an object inside the first object.

```js
var me = {
        name: {
            first: "justin"
        }
    };
    var name = me.name;

    console.log(me.name.first); // "justin"
    console.log(name.first);    // undefined
```

Why am I getting undefined in my second console log? Shouldn't I get "justin" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another name. There is a `name` variable which is global.

```js
var me = {
   name: {
     first: "justin"
   }
};

var anotherName = me.name;

console.log(me.name.first);
console.log(anotherName.first);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that catch! Go figure, will stick to more specific names from now on!